# missing parentheses in ruby, how do i know if it's a variable or a function

Tags: ruby

For example, say we have class called ItemCollection and we call ItemCollection.quantity, since parentheses are not required, how do we know if this accesses the quantity variable in ItemCollection or it calls the quantity() function? Also, for fields in a Ruby class, are they private or public?

The comment answered my question for getters. But what if I have a quantity variable, and a quantity() function that does something else instead of getting/setting quantity's value? How does Ruby determine which one I actually mean?

Comment: You're not *supposed* to know. Suddenly getters and fields are the exact same interface.

Comment: Give an example that you can get quantity variable without a getter?

Comment: The last function that gets defined will override the previous ones.

Comment: When asking questions, try to not be hypothetical. Show actual code and data, errors encountered when running, and whatever else is needed to help us help you deal with actual problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way (except introspection) to have direct access to a variable in a class, only through methods.

Comment: Yep. In addition instance variables are prepended with `@`, class with `@@` and local variables are accessible only inside their scope so they are out of question.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Is it start with lower-case letter(a,b..)?

a. Ruby checks if it is local variable.
b. Ruby checks if it is method.
c. Ruby calls method_missing

#### 2. Is it start with capital letter(A,B..)?

a. Ruby checks if it is constant.
b. Ruby calls const_missing

#### 3.  Is it method call(object.method)?

a. Ruby checks if it is method
b. Ruby calls method_missing

So outside object(as steenslag said) ruby does 3.
Inside your object/class definition it goes with 1/2:

```
class E    
  def a()
    'a'
  end
  def get_a()
    a=42
    puts a 
  end
end
E.new.get_a() #42
```

But in this case:

```
class A
  a=42
  def get_a()
    a
  end
end
A.new.get_a() # NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for #<A:0x3820368>
```

variable **a** belongs to some *version* of **A** so instance of class A and class A by itself doesn't know about **a** after you declare class.